# MS Access VBA - Query Calculations

Tags: vba, ms-access

When I run my query everything works how I need, however, upon initialising the query I receive a prompt for "Enter Parameter Value: Available". the [Required] field attempts to take the results from the [Available] Field to do some calculations. I have managed to do this through two queries but I would prefer to have it all done in one if that is possible.

```
SELECT tblConsumables.PartName, Sum(qryStockMovements.Quantity) AS [Available], tblConsumables.StockMax, IIf([stockmax]-[available]>0,[stockmax]-[available],0) AS Required
FROM tblConsumables INNER JOIN qryStockMovements ON tblConsumables.ID = qryStockMovements.ProductID
GROUP BY tblConsumables.PartName, tblConsumables.StockMax, IIf([stockmax]-[available]>0,[stockmax]-[available],0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need the source expression, not the alias:

```
SELECT tblConsumables.PartName, Sum(qryStockMovements.Quantity) AS [Available], tblConsumables.StockMax, IIf([stockmax]-Sum(qryStockMovements.Quantity) > 0,[stockmax]-Sum(qryStockMovements.Quantity), 0) AS Required
```